# How to allow a GKE Service to authenticate requests internal and external to the cluster?

Tags: authentication, google-kubernetes-engine

We have a GKE cluster with 2 independent API deployments called *Foo* and *Bar*. The Bar API needs to accept requests to its service from applications external to the cluster and internally from service Foo.

My understanding is that for service-to-service authentication, RBAC is used to handle in-cluster auth and for external processes either Workload Identity or an API Gateway service (IAP, Okta, etc.) should be used. Is that the correct thinking here?

Note that we're not dealing with end-user authentication in this scenario, just application-to-application authentication.

Comment: for [Application in the same cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication#application_in_the_same_cluster) use Kubernetes RBAC to grant the Kubernetes service account the permissions that your application requires. you can refer to this documentation on [Authenticating applications](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication#authenticating_applications) for complete reference.

Comment: Are you looking for authentication (the consuming service has an identity) or just access control (limit which services can call which services)?  For external processes, will these be within the same VPC as your cluster or external?